# Include JSP file under WEB-INF folder

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, include

is any way how to include JSP file from local stored folder, under the WEB-INF?

I have in my config.properties defined absolute path *${externalFolder}* to folder which contains external jsp files, controller mapped to */page*  and jsp page *page.jsp* which is in WEB-INF/jsp/ directory.

In this file page.jsp I want to call:

**WEB-INF/jsp/page.jsp**

```
<%@page session="true" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <html>
...
<body>
<jsp:include page="${externalFolder}/someJspFile.jsp" />
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Any file under `WEB-INF` is a protected resource. It will have to be accessed by calling `/WEB-INF/someJspFile.jsp` from a `ServletContext`.

Comment: I know, but I need to have some Jsp files available in external place. Is any way how to solve it?

Comment: Outside of it's Application or WAR file?

Comment: Yes, but on the same server as the application, only different folder.

Comment: Then it's out of your application Servlet context, I don't have an idea on how to take a JSP file that it out of context and add it to your application "servlet" context.

Comment: @PeterJurkovič A JSP is a template that is translated into a Java servlet that must be loaded like any other servlet in the WAR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem, using this custom servlet:  [Content tag lib](http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/cnttag.htm).

> Custom JSP tag. Lets you include file content into current page. Tag is similar to the standard JSP include, but now you may include files that are located outside of your web application. For example:
>
> ```
>  <%@ taglib uri="taglib.tld" prefix="add" %>
>  <add:content file="c:/mydata/myfile.jsp"/>
> ```
>
> Includes content of the given file (.html or .jsp for example). Parameters are:
>    1. `file`: Full path to file
>    2. `flush`: *Optional parameter.* Possible values are true or false. If this value is true tag flushes buffers. Default value is false.
>    3. `cond`: *Optional parameter.* Describes a boolean value tag's behavior depends on. Default value is true (include content).